# Target sales incomplete month Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate the target  sales for an incomplete month in Power BI, but I'm getting stucked. I was thinking about dividing target sales between working days and then I can't follow up. Any ideas please?

Thanks

I tried to divide the target sales of the month between working days.

Comment: Please sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Let's say the target sales for the month of April (20 working days) is 100 usd (5 usd per day) at the end of that month in order to get 100% of target sales, but that today it's April 10th (6 working days) and today the sales are 30 usd, so we are in the target of 100% since we should be selling 5 usd per working day. That should be the result. Not really sure if I'm making myself clear, if not I can provide a screenshot with a data sample. Many thanks